# PhantomJS and Selenium Webdriver - How to clear session

Tags: java, testing, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver (Java) and PhantomJS to test a complex JS driven website. My problem is, that the PhantomJS browser keeps the session between two tests which leads to errors in the test setup.

If I run the tests with Firefox everything works fine because Firefox uses a clean session for every test case.

My first attempt to solve the problem was to just clear the local storage by JS injection. Cookies are deleted by the Selenium exposed `API driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();`

But executing JavaScript without visiting a page is not allowed. So starting the browser at "about:blank" leads to an error.

So, how do I configure my phantomjs webdriver to clear the session?

I'm using phantomjs and webdriver because the selenium-grid services turned out to be not stable enough. So I start my phantomjs instance like that:

```
phantomjs --webdriver=1234
```

Comment: I JUST had the same question! I'm using selenium + phantomjs + wendriver.io + mocha. It just seem logical to start a new session for every test so that they are "clean"...

Comment: Yeah, I think that's some kind of bug or leaky spec inside phantomjs. Because the current url is reset between two tests.

Comment: I have two tests with two different url's, too. But the cookies are clearly leaking over

Comment: I take that back, it seems to work just fine. Here is a test repo + tests: https://github.com/mbrevda/phantomjs-test

Answer (score 7):

The fact that PhantomJS keeps sessions between tests is a [known problem](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/170) in GhostDriver, the Selenium Webdriver implementation in PhantomJS.

I suppose that this problem will be fixed with the PhantomJS 2 release. The bug is already fixed in GhostDriver 1.1.1, but there is no PhantomJS version which includes this GhostDriver version.

Answer (score 2):

I know that Selenium Grid has a "cleanSession" option if you use [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver).   Also, I am pretty sure the regular WebDriver class has a option for this on a local WebDriver instance:

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Comment: I already mentioned that I don't want to use selenium grid. We had it in production and the thing was unstable in the long run. And I already use the deleteAllCookies code - as mentioned in the question.

If you know which option and how to turn it on, please elaborate.

Comment: If you look at the changelog on Selenium 2.40.0, it has a PhantomJS change.  Were you using the latest 2.41.0 grid with ghostdriver?  If not, it might be worth trying again.  I assume you aren't using Chrome or IE.

Comment: ... As stated I use PhantomJS as browser. And I don't use Selenium Grid. I just use regular selenium with its webdriver api. (phantomjs --webdriver=PORT starts the webdriver compatible phantomjs browser). 

But the problem is, that the session is persistant and therefore my webshop starts at a different start point when I run the second test case.

Comment: The change in 2.40.0 might also affect client-side PhantomJS.  Do you use the PhantomJS option: phantom.cookiesEnabled = true; ?   You should have full access to cookies using a JavascriptExecutor object; did you try that?

Comment: Just checked my dependency in my pom.xml. I use 2.40. Puncto Cookies-Enabled. I can rest the cookies via JS. But for that I have to load the page first. Execute the JS and load the Page again. (If I don't do that I get DOM Security exceptions). That sucks pretty much.

Comment: @schlingel You are saying that you "delete all cookies" in your question. To me, this doesn't sound like you used `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()`

Comment: @oberlies I did though. The only thing I had to clear (or at least I tried to do that) by JS injection was the localStorage. Doesn't work nevertheless.
But by running the tests with maven surefire in parallel beats PhantomJS in execution speed anyways.

Comment: @schlingel That is very well possible, but you should put this information into your question, and not somewhere into the comments. You are saying "And I already use the deleteAllCookies code - as mentioned in the question", but "deleteAllCookies" does not occur in your question. So, please edit your question and e.g. explicitly mention the method in code formatting.

Comment: I thought it would be obvious that I'd use the available API. But, why not. But if it makes you happy, I'll update the question for you.

Answer (score 0):

The version 2.0 of PhantomJS fix this issue. If you have a Linux Enviroment, you need clone the sources and compile, like this:

```
git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
cd phantomjs
git checkout 2.0
./build.sh
```

[More info here](http://phantomjs.org/build.html)